# Module not found unless I use a complete path when creating plugins in Hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, hapi.js

I'm trying to familiarise myself with HapiJS and have been playing around with it this week, I've run into a problem with plugins and paths. I get an error regarding the path I specify when I require a file. I can't use " **./** " without getting an error. The only way to overcome the error is to use the full complete path.

Here's my code that works:

```
'use strict';

const indexController = require('/Users/mylaptop/docker-node/controllers/IndexController.js');

module.exports.plugin = {
    name: 'myPlugin',
    version: '1.0.0',
    register: async function (server, options) {

        // Create a route for example
        server.route({
            method:'GET',
            path:'/test',
            handler: function (request, h) {

                return indexController.loadIndex(h);
              }
        });

    }
};
```

However, if I try to require my IndexController file this way:

```
const indexController = require('./controllers/IndexController.js');
```

Then I get this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/mylaptop/docker-node/Users/mylaptop/docker-node/controllers/IndexController.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mylaptop/docker-node/config/routes/index.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

It doesn't work inside of my plugin, yet outside of my plugin, requiring files this way works fine.

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with:

```
const indexController = require('../../controllers/IndexController.js');
```

My project root folder was 2 directories away, hence `../../` working for me.